# How to check a date is expired or not in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, date, dart, time, datepicker

How can i check if a date is expired or not. for eg: if the expire date is 10/01/2021, if the user check today(09/01/2021) it should print "Not Expired", if the user check on 11/01/2021 or after the expiry days it should print "the date is expired". How can i implement this in flutter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`DateTime` type has handy method `isBefore` and `isAfter` to compare two `DateTime` objects.

For example:

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final expirationDate = DateTime(2021, 1, 10);
final bool isExpired = expirationDate.isBefore(now);
```

In this example, `isExpired` variable will be `true` if it has passed the expirationDate and `false` if it has not passed the expiration date.

Comment: Keep in mind that will be midnight *local time*.  So if this is a world-wide moment in time, it should probably be expressed and computed with the UTC interfaces to DateTime.

Comment: I'm a time-zone geek.  You should watch me boil over at mentions of things like DST, or worse, *permanent* DST (WTF!).